# Div rotation not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am testing with CSS and got to a strange behaviour where *transform:rotate* doesn't work, here is an example where the animation doesn't happen: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/wK9WX/)

**CSS**

```
.close {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#00f;
    color:#fff;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.close:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.close, .close:hover {
    -webkit-transition:rotate .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:rotate .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:rotate .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:rotate .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:rotate .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Why is this not working?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You applied the transition to the wrong attribute: ([Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wK9WX/3/))

```css
.close { /* You don't really need .close:hover here */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform .2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform .2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:     -ms-transform .2s ease-in-out;
            transition:         transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

The attribute you want to animate is `transform`. `rotate()` is a transformation function not a CSS property.

Comment: Should it be -webkit on all prefix transform?